# Order by on one query of union in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this

```
SELECT t.id,t.name,t.count 
FROM Teacher 
UNION 
SELECT '','',(SELECT count(*) FROM student)
```

Now I want to use order by only on the first query before union like this

```
SELECT t.id,t.name,t.count 
FROM Teacher 
ORDER BY t.name ASC
UNION 
SELECT '','', (SELECT count(*) FROM student)
```

but it does not work

I have also used

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT t.id,t.name,t.count FROM Teacher) as teacher 
UNION 
SELECT '','',(SELECT count(*) FROM student) 
ORDER BY name ASC
```

but it includes the second query also in the order by and it changes its position also and I don't want order by on the second query only on the first.

Comment: try use (SELECT t.id,t.name,t.count 
FROM Teacher 
ORDER BY t.name ASC)
UNION 
(SELECT '','', (SELECT count(*) FROM student))

Comment: @NigNamza it will not work. check official docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 2):

You cannot order "parts" of a UNION; even if you try to force it with subqueries, MySQL will just disregard it. You can create an extra ordering field though.
here is a generic template for this method:

```
SELECT u.A, u.B, u.C
FROM
(
   SELECT 0 as seq, A, B, C
   FROM table1
   UNION 
   SELECT 1 AS seq, A, B, C
   FROM table2
) AS u
ORDER BY u.seq
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't you need `subquery` :

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id, name, count 
      FROM Teacher 
      UNION 
      SELECT '', '', (SELECT count(*) FROM student)
     ) t
ORDER BY name;
```

Instead, i would rewrite as with single `SELECT` statement :

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id, name, count 
      FROM Teacher 
      UNION 
      SELECT '', '', count(*) 
      FROM student
     ) t
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: But it will also include the second query in the result of order by I dont want to include that the second query  that's the problem

Comment: Those are both equivalent to a non-subqueried union. an ORDER BY following UNIONs is already applied to the results of the UNION. `SELECT * FROM (x UNION y) ORDER BY z` is the same thing as `x UNION y ORDER BY z`

Answer (score 1):

try use () it will let you order by just on first query

```
(SELECT t.id,t.name,t.count FROM Teacher ORDER BY t.name ASC) UNION (SELECT '','', (SELECT count(*) FROM student))
```

Comment: it will not work and it's described explicitly in docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 0):

You need write a subquery and make `seqnum` mark first query and second query then use multiple `order by` on `seqnum` and `name`

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
        SELECT 1 seqnum,t.id,t.name,t.count 
        FROM Teacher 
        UNION 
        SELECT 2,'','', (SELECT count(*) FROM student)
     ) t
ORDER BY t.seqnum,t.name
```